# How to store and update one user record in polymorphic model

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to achieve a feature in which works like a "session", each time a user visits a thread, a profile, their record in this polymorphic table would update accordingly, and not store a separate record each time.

So it's kind of like an activity feed for an individual user each time they visit a page to display their status. This is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't seem to be working.

First Try:

```
if(auth()->user()) {
        if (auth()->user()->visits()->first())
        {
            auth()->user()->visits()->where('user_id', auth()->id())->update([
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                'visitable_id' => $user->id,
                'visitable_type' => get_class($user)
            ]);
        } elseif (empty(auth()->user()->visits()->first()))
        {
            auth()->user()->visits()->create([
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                'visitable_id' => $user->id,
                'visitable_type' => get_class($user)
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Second Try:

```
    if(auth()->user()) {
        auth()->user()->visits()->where('user_id', auth()->id())->updateOrCreate([
            'visitable_id' => $user->id,
            'visitable_type' => get_class($user)
        ]);
    }
```

So what I want to achieve is: I want ONE record for each user, and the visitable_id and visitable_type to update upon visiting each route. I can't seem to get this to work, it always creates new ones, or doesn't create it because it has no "starting point".

Can anyone please help me? Thank you!!

Comment: It will never change. Each user will just create record and it will never again be changed because id and type are the same.

Comment: I'm trying now to delete the records associated with the user before inserting but it is not deleting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first just delete the record that is there by calling the model Visit::where('user_id', auth()->id())->delete() to clear out the existing user activity and then insert the new record :).

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that your relationships are correct.

You are using the `updateOrCreate` the wrong way, you don't need the `where` condition.

The `updateOrCreate` method attempts to find a Model matching the constraints passed as the first parameter. If a matching Model is found, it will update the match with the attributes passed as the second parameter. If no matching Model is found a new Model will be created with both the constraints passed as the first parameter and the attributes passed as the second parameter.

Your code will be like:

```
     if(auth()->user()) {
            auth()->user()->visits()->updateOrCreate(
             [
               'user_id' => auth()->id(),
             ],
             [
                'visitable_id' => $user->id,
                'visitable_type' => get_class($user)
            ]);
        }
```